# Implement Jcrop with Jquery Ui dialog box

Tags: php, jquery, user-interface, jquery-ui-dialog

I am trying to crop an image using Jcrop, I want this functionality in Jquery UI dialog box. I tried as suggested but its not working at all. Please Help.
Thanks

Comment: what's not working for you?
it will help if you will point to the problematic line of code or write down the error you are getting...

Answer (score 4):

Image should be visible when you call Jcrop on it, but it's not cause jQueryUI dialog is not visible.

Here's the workaround I've used.

```
$("#dialog-selector" ).dialog({
  open: function(event, ui) { $('#cropbox').Jcrop(); }
});
```